Why was Kanji used to write certain words in "Signal"?
Signal (2016) is a South Korean murder-mystery detective TV series. In one of the scenes, the main characters analyze the chronology of a serial killing case and write it on a whiteboard:

The text below is Korean (Hangul), but at the top, Before and After are written in Kanji. This made me question why the character, who is obviously Korean, chose to write those two words in Kanji.
Later, one of the detectives contemplates resigning (I'm not stating the reason because of spoilers), and the text seems to be in Kanji:

Is it common to write Japanese in formal scenarios (in this case, a resignation is a formal letter)? How often do Koreans tend to write Japanese or know Japanese?
